# Using the position property use the icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am totally new to the web development. Here I have this icon:

[image: Image Icon]

I am using Font Awesome, and there is no icon that matches that, so I am trying to make a icon using the following way:

```html
<td>
   <div style={positionOf}>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</td>
```

```css
{
   top: 0.3em;
   position: absolute;
}
```

Here I am trying `position : absolute` to the second icon and relative to the first one.

So, but this is not working.
Can any one help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please add some code ?

Comment: You mean the css code ?

Comment: please read [mcve] - you ask us about how to fix your css but show no css?

Comment: @pete Sorry for that Let me just add that code.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your code is working you have to give some values to the icons. By giving some values to the icon they will be indented. Use the following Properties.

```
top : 14px;
left : 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this consider the classes that Font Awesome provides (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/)

```css
.fa-check-circle,
.fa-envelope {
  color: green;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script data-search-pseudo-elements src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>

<span>
<i class="fa fa-envelope" data-fa-transform="grow-15"></i>
<span class="fa-stack ">
<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-1x" data-fa-transform="left-20 down-18"></i>
<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-stack-1x" data-fa-transform="left-20 down-18"></i>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Second icon is I think different.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<div>
    <span class="icon-outer">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>

.icon-outer{
  position:relative;
}
.fa-envelope{
  font-size:30px;
  color:green;
}
.fa-check-circle{
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  bottom:0px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/wzvaqspr/7/